# Grouping with associated variables

Tags: mysql

i have a table as below:

```
Account no.    Login Name    Numbering
1234           rty234        1
1234           bhoin1        1
3456           rty234        2
3456           0hudp         2
9876           cfrdk         3
```

From the table above, you can see that rty234 and bhoin1 registered a same account no of 1234, thus i know that rty234 and bhoin1 are related and i numbered them as 1. The numbering field was based on the account no.
Then I found that rty234 also registered another account no of 3456 and the same account no was registered by 0hudp as well. Thus, i concluded that rty234, bhoin1 and 0hudp are related. Therefore, i wanted to renumber the third and forth row to 1. If they are not further related, then just remain the numbering. How can i achieve that using mysql.

The expected output will be as follow:

```
Account no.    Login Name    Numbering    New_Numbering
1234           rty234        1            1
1234           bhoin1        1            1
3456           rty234        2            1
3456           0hudp         2            1
9876           cfrdk         3            3
```

Comment: what do you want the output to be?

Comment: Please give a sample output. Cheers

Comment: Are open to use procedure?

Comment: Sample output plz.

Comment: Select *, 1 x from my_table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to understand how to design a relational database.**

These groupings that you want to make with the `New_Numbering` field should be done at the time the accounts are registered.  I see two pieces of arbitrary information that needs to be tracked: account number and login name.  Seems like the people registering the account can type whatever they want here, effectively, perhaps account numbers must be numerical.  That detail doesn't matter.

What you want here is one account which can have multiple account numbers associated with it, and multiple logins.  I would also assume that future development may add more to this, for example - why do people need multiple logins?  Maybe different people are using them, or different applications.  Presumably, we could collect additional information about the login names that stores additional details about each login.  The same could be said about account numbers - certainly they contain more detail than just an account number.

*First, you need one main `login` table.*
You describe rty234 and bhoin1 as if they are unique people.  So make this is a `login_name` column which is a unique index in a `login` table.  This table should have an auto-increment `login_id` as the primary key.  Probably this table also has a `password` field and additional information about that person.

*Second, create an `account` table.*
After creating their login, make them register an account with that login.  Make this a two-step process.  When they offer a new account number, create a record for it in the `account` table with additional identifying information that only the account-holder would know.  Somehow you have to validate that this is actually their account in order to create this record, I would think.  This table would also contain an auto-incremented primary key called `account_id` in addition to `account_no` and probably other details about the account.

*Third, create a `login_account` table.*
Once you validate that a login actually should have access to an account, create a record here.  This should contain a `login_id` and an `account_id` which connects these two tables.  Additionally, it might be good to include the information provided which shows that this login should have access to this account.

Now, when you want to query this data, you can find groups of data that have the same login_id or account_id, or even that share either a login or an account with a specific registration.  Beyond that, it gets hairy to do in an SQL query.  So if you really want to be able to go through the data and see who is in the same organization or something, because they share either a login or an account with the same group, you have to have some sort of script.

*Create an `organization` table.*
This table should contain an `organization_id` so you can track it, but probably once you identify the group you'll want to add a name or additional notes, or link it to additional functionality.  You can then also add this `organization_id` field to the `login` or `account` tables, so you can fill them once you know the organization.  You have to think about if it's possible for two organizations to share accounts, and maybe there's a more complicated design necessary.  But I'm going to keep it simple here.

Your script should load up all of the `login_id` and `account_id` values and cache them somewhere.  Then go through them all and if they have an `organization_id`, put their `login_id` or `account_id` in a hashmap with the value as the `organization_id`.  Then load up all of the `login_account` records.  If either the `login_id` or `account_id` has an `organization_id` in its hashmap, then add the other to its hashmap with the same `organization_id`.  (if there's already one there, it would violate the simple organization uniqueness assumption I made, but this is where you would handle complexity - so I would just throw an exception and see if it happens when I run the script)

Hopefully this is enough example to get you started.  When you properly design a database like this, you allow the information to connect naturally.  This makes column additions and future updates much easier.  Good luck!